# string with negative value converted to float

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have django/python project, and a user enters a negative value as a string. But when I try to convert the string to a float I get an error.

I understand that I am not using the hyphen or negative symbol but can not figure out how to replace the dash with a negative symbol.

```
import os, sys
from moneyed import Money
from moneyed.localization import format_money


moneystring = str('-$180.00')
print Money(float(moneystring.strip("$").replace(',', '')), 'USD')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./moneytest.py", line 31, in 
>       print Money(float(moneystring.strip("$").replace(',', '')), 'USD')
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: -$180.00

Comment: The `.strip(..)` will not work, since the leading character is a minus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.replace(..)` or something else that can remove characters to remove the dollar, like:

```
moneystring = '-$180.00'
print Money(float(moneystring.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')), 'USD')
```

This is necessary, since `.strip(..)` removes *leading* and *trailing* characters. But for the string `'-$180.00'`, `$` is *not* a leading or trailing character.

That being said, I strongly advice you *not* to use `float(..)`, since it is inprecise. `Money` internally uses a decimal. So you better process this like:

```
from moneyed import Money, USD

moneystring = '-$180.00'
print Money(moneystring.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')), USD)
```

Comment: Thank you the code you provided resolved my issues.